# FaceDetector android не работает на тяжолых фото

Tags: android

FaceDetector в android вылетает при попытке работы с фото размер которых больше 3-4 МБ. Как можно решить проблему? 
Вот код:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.testimage);
    }

    public void clickBtn(View view) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable = true;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.testimage, options);

        Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
        myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false).build();
        if (!faceDetector.isOperational()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cold not set up the Face Detector!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
            float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
            float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
            float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
            float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
            tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
    }
}
```

А вот ошибка:

02-20 20:02:06.821 3636-3636/com.example.viktor.facedetector E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.viktor.facedetector, PID: 3636
                                                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 385786812 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 254MB until OOM
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
                                                                                   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
                                                                                   at com.example.viktor.facedetector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки при вылете добавьте в вопрос